# How to copy iPhone photos/videos to Mac?

Tags: iphone, photos

It sounds very simple. I want to move my iPhone photos and videos to my Macbook so that I can upload them to Google Drive. There are tens of thousands of photos that need to be moved. "Image Capture" doesn't work. Sometimes it doesn't copy some photos and it hangs sometimes, etc. If I sync my photos to the Photos app, they go in this weird photos library file structure which is harder to extract. What are my other choices?

Directly uploading from my iPhone to Google Drive doesn't work either. I cannot select all in the app and it will probably hang in the middle.

Comment: IMO you should use iCloud Photos to get them to your Mac. Ask a different question to figure out how to get the `Photos Library.photoslibrary` folder structure into Google Photos / Google Drive.

Comment: Are you looking to extract only photos and videos for saving in Google Drive, or also the album/folder structure, metadata etc.? Sync to Mac Photos via iCloud, then there are many tools for exporting, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 2):

> they go in this weird photos library file structure which is harder to extract

Once you get them in the Photos app, you can drag them to a folder in finder, and they'll just be there as files without any weird directory structure.

Or **File > Export**